# offending class deploying grails war generated with intellij idea

Tags: tomcat, grails, intellij-idea, deployment

I recently recreated an old Grails project (with version 2.1.5) using Intellij Idea 2017.2.2. When I create the war file and try to deploy it in a stand alone tomcat, I get the messages:

`INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/xapp/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Aug 21, 2017 11:48:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/xapp/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.39.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class`

Any hints on how to exclude those classes so they are not included in the war file ?

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the tomcat dependencies in your BuildConfig.groovy plugins closure to one of `build ":tomcat:7.0.55"` or `provided ":tomcat:7.0.55"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude files from your war like this, in your BuildConfig:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
  delete(file: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar")
}
```